# Removing whitespace after splitting a string in python

Tags: string, parsing, indexing, removing-whitespace

```
1)Prompt the user for a string that contains two strings separated by a comma.
2)Report an error if the input string does not contain a comma. Continue to prompt until a valid string is entered. Note: If the input contains a comma, then assume that the input also contains two strings.
3)Using string splitting, extract the two words from the input string and then remove any spaces. Output the two words.
4)Using a loop, extend the program to handle multiple lines of input. Continue until the user enters q to quit.
```

I wrote a program with these instructions although I cannot work out how to remove extra spaces that may be attached to the outputted words. For example if you enter "Billy, Bob" it works fine, but if you enter "Billy,Bob" you will get an IndexError: list index out of range, or if you enter "Billy , Bob" Billy will be outputted with an extra space attached to the string. Here is my code.

```
usrIn=0
while usrIn!='q':
    usrIn = input("Enter input string: \n")
    if "," in usrIn:
        tokens = usrIn.split(", ")
        print("First word:",tokens[0])
        print("Second word:",tokens[1])
        print('')
        print('')
    else:
        print("Error: No comma in string.")
```

How do I remove  spaces from the outputs so I can just use a usrIn.split(",") ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `.trim()` method which will remove leading and trailing white-spaces. 
`usrIn.trim().split(",")`. After this is done you can split them again using the white-space regex, for instance, `usrIn.split("\\s+")`
The `\s` will look for white space while the + operator will look for repeated white-spaces.

Hope this helps :)